# Refactor multiple If else if statement using Delegates

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, delegates

I wrote a method to select the filters(two or more) based on the true/false conditions.Below is the method I used for selecting the multiple filters.

```
public T SetPropertyTypes<T>(bool residential, bool commercial) where T : IPage, new()
    {

        // Residential Property Type Check logic
        if (residential && (ElementIsNotActive(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeResidentialCss))).Invoke(Driver)))
            ClickButton(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeResidentialCss)), "Residential");
        else if (ElementIsActive(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeResidentialCss))).Invoke(Driver))
            ClickButton(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeResidentialCss)), "Residential");

        // Commercial Property Type Check logic
        if (commercial && (ElementIsNotActive(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeCommercialCss))).Invoke(Driver)))
            ClickButton(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeCommercialCss)), "Commercial");
        else if (ElementIsActive(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeCommercialCss))).Invoke(Driver))
            ClickButton(() => FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeCommercialCss)), "Commercial");
    }
```

Later I found that the code is redundant and it could be better if I make it simpler and non-ambiguous.I'm new to C#, I'm not aware of much features, Is there any way to refactor this using any features of C#?

I tried using checking the variables using if-else-if but that's not working as intended behavior.

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: You should try ReSharper tool.

Comment: It would help if you explained in English the logic steps you intended with this code. You seem to be doing a lot of extra checking. An explanation might be: if `residential` is `true` then click the element located by `propertyTypeResidentialCss`.

Comment: One suggestion is to not define strings as part of locators, use the `By` class instead. So don't define `propertyTypeResidentialCss`, instead define `By propertyTypeResidentialLocator = By.CssSelector(...);`. Now you can pass around the `By` reference and not have to guess what type of locator it is or have a method for each locator type, id, CSS selector, XPath, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without much details, simple refactoring looks like this:

```
    public T SetPropertyTypes<T>(bool residential, bool commercial) where T : IPage, new()
    {
        TryClick(residental, propertyTypeResidentialCss, "Residential");
        TryClick(commercial, propertyTypeCommercialCss, "Commercial");
    }

    private void TryClick(bool clickIfNotActive, object propType, string btnName)
    {
        var elem = FindElement(By.CssSelector(propType));
        bool isActive = ElementIsActive(() => elem).Invoke(Driver);
        if (clickIfNotActive && !isActive || isActive)
            ClickButton(() => elem, btnName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is good! If you are just looking to clean up the code a little bit there are a few things you could do.

1. you have a bool method parameter for both options(residential and commercial) but there seem to only be two options. you could simplify the method signature to just one bool for residential, if false then you know the other option is commercial.
2. I see an IPage interface and a Driver so Im going to assume your writing a selenium based app.you could abstract the code out that is doing the CSS lookup with a webdriver. It looks like you already have a couple functions that are checking element state and clicking a button. you could condense the code down a little by calling straight into the webdriver.

I dont know what you are doing in the other function calls but assuming its just calling driver methods your code might look like :

```
public void SetPropertyTypes(bool residential)
{

    IWebElement _resident = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeResidentialCss));
    IWebElement _commercial = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(propertyTypeCommercialCss));

    // Residential Property Type Check logic
    if (residential || _resident.Enabled ) // or _resident.Displayed depending on what you are doing
        _resident.Click();
    else
        _commercial.Click();
}
```

Hope this helps!